# AWK column from a script param?

Tags: awk

I want to call awk from a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -vFPAT='[^ ]*|"[^"]*"|\\[[^]]*\\]' '{ print $2 }' $1
```

I want $2 to be a number that I specify. So if the script is named get-log-column I'd like to be able to call it this way: get-log-column /var/log/apache2/access.log 4

In this example, 4 would be the column so the output would be column 4 from access.log.

In other words, if access.log looked like this:

```
alpha beta orange apple snickers 
paris john michael peace world
```

So the output would be:

```
apple
peace
```

Comment: Seems your `"` and `'` characters were not correctly pasted in your post, so edited them now, request you to be careful while pasting contents into the posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: @tripleee, Hi sir, IMHO, I know it is duplicate of how to pass a shell variable into awk, since OP's question has to club it with printing as a specific column with value of variable that is the reason I haven't closed it as a dup. If I missed something then kindly do let me know I will make it dup ASAP then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
#!/bin/bash
var="$1"
awk -v FPAT='[^ ]*|"[^"]*"|\\[[^]]*\\]' -v varcol="$var" '{ print $varcol }' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

Have created a shell variable `var` which will have `$1` value in it. Where `$1` value is the argument passed to script. Now in `awk` we can't pass shell variables directly so created 1 `awk` variable named `var_col` which will have value of `var` in it. Now mentioning `$varcol` will print column value from current line as per OP's question. `$` means field number and `varcol` is a variable which has user entered value in it.

Comment: I could use an if statement ... but this seems clunky.

Comment: @KevinSwindon, you mean you want to insert it as a new column? Sorry I am confused now.

Comment: I want to display column #4 if I use 4 in my command line argument.

Comment: @KevinSwindon, then I need not to change anything in my script it will work. Create a new test script paste this code and run it like `./test.ksh 4` and it should fly then

Comment: @KevinSwindon, Could you please do let me know if this answer helped you?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Ravinder! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v var="$1" -v FPAT='[^ ]*|"[^"]*"|\\[[^]]*\\]' '{ print $var }' $1
```

See this on how to use variable from shell in `awk`
[How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks, cut and past from OP original post that was wrong.